# Remove line at 80 characters in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image]

When I have lines of code that approach or exceed 80 characters in Google Colab, a dashed vertical line appears at the 80-character mark. How can I disable/hide/remove this line?

Comment: This is not about programming per se

Comment: The line in question is added by CodeMirror, and is referred to as a "ruler".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select 'Preferences' in the Tools menu, then change the value of the 'Vertical ruler column' setting from 80 to 0.

[image]